# How to Access Apache Tomcat from Browser when successfully startup

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat, server

I successfully started ***Apache Tomcat 8.5.9*** from shell comands on ***Linux*** server.

[image]

And change the port 8080 to 8880 on the file **server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8880" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

but when I try to access to Apache Tomcat from browser, never entered to the interface.

Example: X.X.X.X:8880

[image]

Did I miss something? I need to configure something else?

Any Help will be really grateful. Thanks, Regards.

Comment: did you check catalina.out that tomcat started correctly. if so, then maybe a forewall issue?

Answer (score 2):

First of all check port 8880 is in LISTENING state:

```
netstat -nltp | grep 8880
```

Here is my output example of port 8080:

```
netstat -nltp | grep 8080

tcp      0      0 0.0.0.0:8080      0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      4052/java
```

If it is ok then check catalina.log file. If no check catalina.log why startup script is failing.